# $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^{1-\frac{1}{p}}}\int_0^xf=0$ where $f \in L^p$ $1<p<\infty$[Proof verification]

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^{1-\frac{1}{p}}}\int_0^xf=0$ where $f \in L^p$ $1<p<\infty$.

Proof: We  approximate $f$ with the functions $f\chi_{[-n,n]}$. This sequence of functions converges in $L^p$ norm to $f$. The statement is clearly true for functions with compact support, thus $|\frac{1}{x^{1-\frac{1}{p}}}\int_0^xf|\leq |\frac{1}{x^{1-\frac{1}{p}}}\int_0^x(f-f_n)|+|\frac{1}{x^{1-\frac{1}{p}}}\int_0^xf_n|<\epsilon$ by picking $n$ big enough so that $||f-f_n||<\epsilon/2$ and $x$ big enough so that for that $n$, $|\frac{1}{x^{1-\frac{1}{p}}}\int_0^xf_n|<\epsilon/2$ This concludes the proof.

Comment: Yes, the idea seems right. But you have to write more clearly the details.
In which order do you pick $x$ and $n$ large enough?
How do you control the difference term by $\|f-f_n\|$ (This is the $L^p$ norm I suppose?)

Comment: I pick n first, then x. Since $f_ \to f$ in $L^p$ norm I can control that term.

Comment: I was saying you should detail how you control $\left|x^{1/p−1} ∫_0^x (f −f_n)\right|$ by $∥f−f_n∥_{L^p}$ (Hölder's inequality I suppose?)

Comment: @LL3.14 ah, yes. My apologies, it is Holders inequalty